# Redux Connect: mapDispatchToProps pass in the result of an action creator

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm learning redux and and wanted to know how dispatch passes in result of an action creator as stated in the screenshot below taken from redux doc.

The learning app code is available here: https://github.com/ZhangMYihua/lesson-12/tree/master/src

As per the course instructor the below mapDispatchToProps code updates the header component state using user.action.js. I'm not able to understand how all this works even after reading the redux documentation.https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setCurrentUser: user => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user))
});
```

1. The initial state of the currentUser in the header component is set using the user.reducer.js file in the redux folder. This part is clear.
2. When we sign in using Google SignIn, the createUserProfileDocument(userAuth) function in App.js will check if the google login is available in the firestore users collections. If not it will create a copy of the account with the required fields. The user login details are fetched from the firestore users collections which are passed in the userRef in App.js.

What i do not understand is how data from userRef in componentDidMount() gets passed to header component using dispatch when we login using google signin?

```
componentDidMount() {

    const {setCurrentUser} = this.props;

    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {

     if (userAuth) {
       const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);

       userRef.onSnapshot(snapShot => {
         setCurrentUser({
             id: snapShot.id,
             ...snapShot.data()
           });
         });

     }
```

Below is the example from the react-redux documentation which is similar to the above.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part in your `componentDidMount` is passing `userRef` data to the redux store:

```js
const {setCurrentUser} = this.props;

// ...

setCurrentUser({
  id: snapShot.id,
  ...snapShot.data()
});
```

**mapDispatchToProps**

The code calls `this.props.setCurrentUser` and that is function which you define in your `mapDispatchToProps`.

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setCurrentUser: user => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user))
});
```

So `this.props.setCurrentUser` function definition is simple like this (where dispatch is defined in upper scope):

```js
this.props.setCurrentUser = user => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user))
```

The function takes a single parameter `user` and calls `dispatch(setCurrentUser(user))`. Here the `setCurrentUser(user)` is your action creator that produce some action (something like this `{action: 'SET_CURRENT_USER', payload: {user}}`). This action is dispatched to `redux` store with `dispatch` function (the `react-redux` passes correct `dispatch` function to your `mapDispatchToProps` through `react-redux` `connect`, see bellow).

**connect**

The `mapDispatchToProps` is useless if you are not use it as an argument of the `react-redux` `connect` function. You usually wrap your component with `connect` and export the wrapped component not just the component itself. So whenever you import your App.js module and use the default export from it as component in some JSX tree, it is not just your component, but it is your component wrapped with `react-redux` magic. This magic ensures, that the mapDispatchToProps is called with correct dispatch argument (`store.dispatch` from `redux` library) and enhances your component props object with another properties, the ones form `mapStateToProps` and the ones from `mapDispatchToProps`.

```js
// here you are wrapping your App component with `connect` from `react-redux`
export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

In next file you will import and use the wrapped component like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './redux/store';

import App from './App'; // here you are importing the wrapped component

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

It is necessary to have your components which uses `react-redux` have wrapped with Provider in the app component tree. Otherwise `connect` will not have access to `redux` store so *connecting* component to `redux` store won't work.

*EDIT*

**mapStateToProps**

`this.props.setCurrentUser` is used to dispatching action to your redux store which just MODIFIES it (how the store is modified is up to your implementation of `reducer` - see [user.reducer.js](https://github.com/ZhangMYihua/lesson-12/blob/master/src/redux/user/user.reducer.js) in your example).

If you want to access some part of your `redux` store, you need to pass the `mapStateToProps` by the first argument (see above that in example of your `App` component the first argument of `connect` was `null`).

You can imagine the redux store as a single javascript object. The first definition of this object you can see in your [root-reducer.js](https://github.com/ZhangMYihua/lesson-12/blob/master/src/redux/root-reducer.js):

```js
export default combineReducers({
  user: userReducer
});
```

This defines that your `redux` store (object) has the property `user` on the top level. The value of property `user` handles [user.reducer.js](https://github.com/ZhangMYihua/lesson-12/blob/master/src/redux/user/user.reducer.js). That reducer defines initial value of the `user` part of the store and also defines how it can be modified (by redux actions). So according to your example your initial store is this:

```js
{
  user:  {
    currentUser: null
  }
}
```

If you want access it in your component (props) you need to use `mapStateToProps` as I stated above, like this (see the file [header.component.jsx](https://github.com/ZhangMYihua/lesson-12/blob/master/src/components/header/header.component.jsx) in your example):

```js
// header.component.jsx

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ // react-redux passes here the whole redux store to the argument state
  /*
   you want access currentUser of user reducer,
   so you just access it the same way as you would do it
   in javascript object, with use of dots.
  */
  currentUser: state.user.currentUser // 
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

And then you access the connected store value in your component by props:

```js
// whenever in your component code
console.log(this.props.currentUser);
```

Comment: Thanks Lavor. This is really helpful and better explained than the redux documentation

Comment: how can i console.log(this.props.setCurrentUser) to see the value of userRef ?

Comment: You can't. `this.props.setCurrentUser` is FUNCTION that dispatches action to your redux store (so IT MODIFIES the store object). If you want to GET THE VALUE of the store object, you need to map store to your component by `mapStateToProps`, see EDIT section in my answer. I would suggest you to read some getting started of the `redux` and `react-redux` to understand basic concepts.